# grep find when string has changed / create time bars

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to extract data from a file with a timestamp as below:

```
20110103T000204000 
20110103T000229000 
20110103T000253000 
20110103T000258000 
20110103T000330000 
20110103T000523000 
20110103T000536000
```

the four characters after the T represent HHMM Hours and minutes. How can I extract line when either:

1. Those 4 characters have changed.
   OR
2. More difficult (I guess) by change in "BAR" - either every 5 minutes, 10mins or 1hour etc.

So for 1 I could get:

```
20110103T000204000 
20110103T000330000 
20110103T000523000
```

and for 2:

```
20110103T000004000 
20110103T000530000 
20110103T001023000 
20110103T001504000 
20110103T002030000 
20110103T002523000
```

Comment: Example for your conditions?

Answer (score 2):

grep isn't going to be enough for you.  Here's the start of a Perl program that should help.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $current_datetime = '';
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my $datetime = substr( $line, 0, 13 );
    if ( $datetime ne $current_datetime ) {
        print $line, "\n";
        $current_datetime = $datetime;
    }
}
```

Save that as whatever.pl, and execute it as

```
perl whatever.pl yourinputfile
```

And you should get the output

```
20110103T000204000 
20110103T000330000 
20110103T000523000
```

Does that give you a good place to start?